# Toggle Boolean property inside Object in Array of Objects in state

Tags: reactjs, object, boolean

I have an array of Objects in state, like so:

```
this.state = {
  week: [
    {
      en: 'Mon',
      morn: false,
      night: false,
    },
//... the rest of the days...
```

I can successfully toggle the `morn` and `night` Booleans, like so:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
      prevState.week.map(day => {
        if (target.includes(day.en)) {
          if (target.includes('morn')) {
            day.morn = !day.morn;
          //^ right here
          }
          if (target.includes('night')) {
            day.night = !day.night;
          //^ and here
          }
        }
        return day;
      });
    });
```

eslint complains: `Assignment to property of function parameter 'day'`.

Comment: your `eslint` don't like that you are mutate the `day` argument, and he has a point.

you should return new object.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this because your linter has the following rule enabled:
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign

> Assignment to variables declared as function parameters can be misleading and lead to confusing behavior, as modifying function parameters will also mutate the arguments object. Often, assignment to function parameters is unintended and indicative of a mistake or programmer error.
>
> This rule can be also configured to fail when function parameters are modified. Side effects on parameters can cause counter-intuitive execution flow and make errors difficult to track down.

---

Do solve this, you could create a copy of your `day` object, which you can modify and return that instead:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  prevState.week.map(day => {
    const tempDay = {...day};
    if (target.includes(day.en)) {
      if (target.includes('morn')) {
        tempDay.morn = !day.morn;
      }
      if (target.includes('night')) {
        tempDay.night = !day.night;
      }
    }
    return tempDay;
  });
});
```

Comment: That almost did it, thanks! It was just const tempDay = day. Great!

Comment: @StamatisDeliyannis, glad it helped. Though you should do `const tempDay = {...day}` as that makes a copy whereas const `tempDay = day` only creates a new reference to the same object. Also, if this helped, please consider marking this answer as the accepted one and/or up-voting. Good luck

Comment: The final solution actually came by googling all eslint errors. I made the code better and readable by making a copy of the state object, manipulate it, and then replace the original with the new object.